# ActiveRecord::UnknownAttributeError: unknown attribute: contractor_id

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4

I have dumb question.
I have some models:

```
class Contractor < User
  has_many :contractorEs
  has_many :customers
end

class Customer < User
  belongs_to :contractor
  has_many :customerEs
end
```

When I try

```
c = Contractor.first
c.customers.build
```

I have `ActiveRecord::UnknownAttributeError: unknown attribute: contractor_id`
But I have migration

```
class AddContractorIdToCustomers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_column :customers, :contractor_id, :integer
  end
end
```

Where is the problem?

Edited:
Yes, I run migration and tried to restart server.

Comment: did you run rake db:migrate after generating the migration?

Answer (score 1):

Did you remember to *run* the migration?

`rake db:migrate`